# Best puzzles of 2020 Q3 (July - September)?

Tags: discussion, best-of

*This question is part of the [best-puzzle award series](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-of).*

---

> What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the third quarter ( July / August / September ) 2020?
>
> ---

Suggested guidelines for nomination:

- Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.
- No more than 3 nominations per person.
- Don't nominate your own puzzles.
- Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.
- **In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.**

---

Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):

> **Algorithmically selected "best of"**:
>
> - [***Popular puzzles***, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2020 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/509699/popular-puzzles-quaterly?year=2020&month=07#query-results)
> - [Well received puzzles ***you may have missed*** from 2020 Q3](https://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/871694/puzzles-you-may-have-missed-quaterly?year=2020&month=07#query-results)
>
> **Best by votes/views:**
>
> - [Questions with the most ***votes*** from 2020 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106579?StartDate=2020/07/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the most ***views*** from 2020 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106705?StartDate=2020/07/01#query-results)
> - [Questions with the highest-voted ***answers*** from 2020 Q3](http://data.stackexchange.com/puzzling/query/106709?StartDate=2020/07/01#query-results)

---

<sub>Meta-meta issues:</sub>

- <sub>Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?</sub>

  - <sub>Yes, [Photography SE](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2657/weekly-featured-image-ongoing-contest) and [Sci-fi/Fantasy SE](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3142/31394) do something very similar.</sub>
- <sub>What's the point?</sub>
- <sub>To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.</sub>
- <sub>To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.</sub>
- <sub>To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

### [Suspected felicide in the Schrödinger household](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102248/suspected-felicide-in-the-schr%c3%b6dinger-household) by [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe)

One cryptic from jafe has already been nominated, but I felt this one deserved special mention as well. The Schrödinger clues in this puzzle were very nice - especially given that some of the clues had *more* than two solutions, all working perfectly! And of course, the most striking of these clues had jafe's signature geographic flair.

Answer (score 5):

### [This new puzzle type needs a name {EXTREME EDITION}](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/102465) by [Stiv](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/60644/stiv)

Stiv had several great puzzles this quarter, but for sheer epic artistry, none could match this tour de force stacking nine different grid-deductions into a single diagram. There are so many different vectors (alpha-numerics, colours, shapes) for conveying cluing information that Stiv managed to get into the grid without interfering with each other...just a gem. I can't say it didn't get enough love at the time, because it was (rightly) very well received, but I have no remorse about promoting it again.

Answer (score 2):

### [Just a little adventure in cylindrical crosswordland](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/99848/just-a-little-adventure-in-cylindrical-crosswordland/99857#comment283855_99857) by [jafe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/41973/jafe)

Of course, jafe has produced a large number of excellent puzzles. But this one stuck out to me as being particularly well crafted. The nature of the puzzle required an unusual graphic which jafe created excellently. The clues were all tight, and I just remember it as a particularly enjoyable solve.

Answer (score 2):

### [Fun with ^#**#!@ flags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100151/fun-with-flags) by [Jeremy Dover](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/users/69217/jeremy-dover)

Seriously, this puzzle combines [flags](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flags) and [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher). Do you need any more explanation?

Okay, I'll put some more explanation. The amount of information and hints packed into the story and picture, along with how funny the story is, makes this a very very good puzzle. Also, did I mention that there's a ***cipher*** involving ***flags***? As a wise Stiv [once said](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/14524?m=56027834#56027834):

> Always love a good flag puzzle, and that was a good flag puzzle :)